# OSX: Generate MD5 checksum recursively in a textfile containing files with corresponding checksum

Tags: shell-script, osx, hashsum

In a directory withmultiple subdirectories but only one folder deep containing tiff-files I'd like to generate a md5 checksum that writes the filename with the corresponding checksum into a textfile.

For example in directory TIFF I have 2 subdirectories:

```
TIFF
  |- b0125TIFF
        |- b_0000_001.tif
        |- b_0000_002.tif
        |- b_0000_003.tif
        |- b_0000_004.tif
  |- c0126TIFF
        |- c_0000_001.tif
        |- c_0000_002.tif
        |- c_0000_003.tif
        |- c_0000_004.tif
```

My expected textfile (checksum should be of course different):

```
** foo.md5:
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *b0125TIFF/b_0000_001.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *b0125TIFF/b_0000_002.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *b0125TIFF/b_0000_003.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *b0125TIFF/b_0000_004.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *c0126TIFF/c_0000_001.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *c0126TIFF/c_0000_002.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *c0126TIFF/c_0000_003.tif
188be1dbd4f6bcfdef8d25639473e6ec *c0126TIFF/c_0000_004.tif
```

How can I achieve that?

I know that this generates the checksum recursively in one directory:

```
find -s . -type f -exec md5 -q {} \; | md5
```

Comment: This is what `md5` does by default if you leave the `-q` flag out and give it multiple files... Are you not happy with the default output of `md5`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. I started the command find -s . -type f -exec md5 -q {} \; | md5 and will check the result but it takes several hours (have 3TB on tiff files). Will close the question afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to pass the output of the `find` and `md5` through `md5`, that would just give you an MD5 checksum of a lot of MD5 checksums...

---

```
$ find TIFF -type f -name '*.tif' -exec md5 {} ';' >md5.txt
$ cat md5.txt
MD5 (TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-1.tif) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-2.tif) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-3.tif) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-1.tif) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-2.tif) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-3.tif) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

The `md5` implementation on macOS does not support verifying checksums with `md5 -c` unfortunately, but the `shasum` utility does:

```
$ find TIFF -type f -name '*.tif' -exec shasum {} ';' >sums.txt
$ cat sums.txt
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-1.tif
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-2.tif
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-3.tif
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-1.tif
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-2.tif
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-3.tif

$ shasum -c sums.txt
TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-1.tif: OK
TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-2.tif: OK
TIFF/b0125TIFF/file-3.tif: OK
TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-1.tif: OK
TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-2.tif: OK
TIFF/c0126TIFF/file-3.tif: OK
```

`shasum` calculates the SHA1 hash of a file by default.

Comment: The creation of md5 checksums work great, thank you very much! But when I try $ md5 -c md5.txt I get md5: illegal option -- c
usage: md5 [-pqrtx] [-s string] [files ...]

Comment: @EmilyChoi Ah, the `md5` on macOS does not have the `-c` flag. Then you may either use `shasum` instead or install GNU coreutils and use `md5sum` from there. I will add the `shasum` variation to my answer soon.

Comment: great, thank you very much! Just a note: I was trying the "find TIFF -type f -name '*.tif' -exec md5 {} ';' >md5.txt" on linux and I'm getting "find: 'md5': No such file or directory" Do you know what's causing it? On OSX it works.

Comment: @EmilyChoi Yes, `md5` is not available on Linux. You may try `md5sum` there. Use `md5sum --tag` (I think) to get the same format output as on macOS. There's also `sha1sum` that generates the same kind of output as `shasum` on macOS.  These Linux commands come from the GNU coreutils package and are often installed by default.

Comment: sorry, one more question raised up as I'm generating and checking md5 checksums: How can I write the output of the check into a textfile in linux? $ md5sum -c sums.txt > sums_checked_results.txt doesn't work

Comment: @EmilyChoi Huh? That should work just fine. In what specific way does it not work?

Comment: yes, I was too impatient. After a few minutes the filesize of sums_checked_results.txt increased from 0 bytes. Thanks for helping!